nvim snippets how to create custom peace of codes
I try to write some custom snippets. For that I install and configure Luasnip in my nvim.cmp.  Also installed rafamadriz/friendly-snippets
So far it is ok; means autocompletion shows snippets from friendly-snippets.
Then I tried this:

Create package.json (following the example found in friendly-snippets folder) in my ~/.config/nvim
Create a subfolder called my-snippets in ~/.config/nvim
Create a file html.json in that subfolder (following the syntax found in friendly-snippets folder)
Modify nvim.cmp so that luasnip loads snippets found in my my-snippets subfolder.
Save everything
Restart nvim

Then don't see my snippet.  Also tried to disable friendly-snippets but not working too.
Here are my config :
package.json in ~/.config/nvim
    {
    "name": "friendly-snippets",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.11.0"
    },
    "contributes": {
        "snippets": [
            {
                "language": [
                    "plaintext",
                    "markdown",
                    "tex",
                    "html",
                    "global",
                    "all"
                ],
                "path": "./my-snippets/global.json"     
        },
        {
                 "language": [
                     "html",
                     "jade",
                     "pug",
                     "eruby",
                     "javascriptreact",
                     "htmldjango",
                     "astro",
             "blade"
                 ],
                 "path": "./my-snippets/html.json"
         },
      ]
    }
}

html.json in ~/.config/nvim/my-snippets
    {
    "html5c": {
        "prefix": "html5c",
        "body": [
            "<!DOCTYPE html>",
            "<html lang=\"$1en\">",
            "\t<head>",
            "\t\t<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">",
            "\t\t<meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1\">",
            "\t\t<title>$2</title>",
            "\t\t<link href=\"$3css/style.css\" rel=\"stylesheet\">",
            "\t</head>",
            "\t<body>",
            "\t$0",
            "\t</body>",
            "</html>"
        ],
        "description": "MCP HTML - Defines a template for a html5 document w/Bootstrap",
        "scope": "text.html"
}

A fragment of nvim-cmp
   "hrsh7th/nvim-cmp",
    event = "InsertEnter",
    dependencies = {
     "hrsh7th/cmp-buffer", -- source for text in buffer
     "hrsh7th/cmp-path", -- source for file system paths
     {
       "L3MON4D3/LuaSnip",
       -- follow latest release.
       version = "v2.*", -- Replace <CurrentMajor> by the latest released major (first   
          number of latest release)
       -- install jsregexp (optional!).
       build = "make install_jsregexp",
     },
     "saadparwaiz1/cmp_luasnip",   -- for autocompletion
     "rafamadriz/friendly-snippets", -- useful snippets
     "onsails/lspkind.nvim",       -- vs-code like pictograms
     "Jezda1337/nvim-html-css",
     },
     config = function()
     local cmp = require("cmp")

     local luasnip = require("luasnip")
     local lspkind = require("lspkind")
     -- loads vscode style snippets from installed plugins (e.g. friendly-snippets)
    require("luasnip.loaders.from_vscode").lazy_load({ paths = {"./my-snippets"} })


So far in  a html file typing html5 will not list html5c snippets.
Hope to be clear enough, I'am newbie with Nvim and lua.
